# Python prints "function <name> at <address>" rather than function output

Tags: python, function, pygame, io, output

Im studying pygame and trying to create a score function. But it doesn't work if I do same thing as the examples. 
 I did everything step by step third time however its doesnt work. 
I need a text that shows me current spent time in game. Then I will turn it to score board.

**My Function For Displaying Score:**

```
def display_score():
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    score_surf = myfont.render(f'{display_score}',False,(64,64,64))
    score_rect = score_surf.get_rect(center = (400, 50))
    screen.blit(score_surf,score_rect)
```

**Create Font For Text:**

`myfont = pygame.font.Font('font/Pixeltype.ttf', 50)`

**All of Screen Displays:** (*Spesificly section three #Functions Part*)

```
    if game_active:
        # Layouts
        screen.blit(sky,(0,0))
        screen.blit(ground,(0,300))

        # Player
        screen.blit(player,player_rect)
        gravity += 1
        player_rect.y += gravity
        if player_rect.bottom >= 300: player_rect.bottom = 300

        # Functions
        display_score()

        # Snail
        screen.blit(snail,snail_rect)
        snail_rect.x -= 3
        if snail_rect.right <= 0: snail_rect.left = 800

        # collision
        if player_rect.colliderect(snail_rect):
            game_active = False
        
    else:
        screen.fill('Yellow')
```

**Whats Wrong:**:
When I launched game, pygame displays text as "function display_score at 0x103e3ab90",
when I try to print it terminal shows "None"

What am I missing?

Comment: Please don't add solutions to the question, especially not as only external links.

Comment: ok ım sorry for this

Comment: You can post a self answer here if you want describing your solution

Answer (score 1):

There are two things wrong with your code:

1. In Python functions are first class objects, like numbers and strings, so in your code you are printing the function object, not the result of calling the function. In order to call the function you must put parenthesis after it, this example will clarify the problem:

```
>>> def func_hello(): print("hello")
... 
>>> func_hello
<function func_hello at 0x7f8ab8698700>
>>> func_hello()
hello
```

2. But if you add parenthesis here: `score_surf = myfont.render(f'{display_score}',False,(64,64,64))`  your function will become infinitely recursive. The fix is making a function `compute_score` that computes the score and calling it from `display_score`, and remembering the parenthesis.

Comment: My english not so bright with terms but it seems you say if I write a function name it will show me function object but if I add paranthesis after it, it will show me results. But I am writing it with paranthesis like this `display_score()` but it is not working. I couldnt understand second example but I tried to understand with adding paranthesis after `score_surf = myfont.render(f'{display_score}',False,(64,64,64))` and get an error.

Comment: @ıLikeJavaButİtsKindaMessy I adressed that in point two, if you call the function within itself in the wrong way you will get infinite recursion, try reading this: https://www.enjoyalgorithms.com/blog/recursion-explained-how-recursion-works-in-programming

Comment: The correct place to put parenthesis is `score_surf = myfont.render(f'{display_score()}',False,(64,64,64))` but as i said before this will still give you an error